# setTimeout event doesn't fire when storing timer id in specific variable

Tags: javascript, settimeout

**I found the answer to this while I was typing it up, thought I'd still post it just in case it helps someone**

I'm sure no one will be able to reproduce this, but what the heck. :)

We have a page that fires off an AJAX call after some user input. After some user input we wait a bit, using setTimeout, to avoid calling the AJAX method before the user finishes typing. Nothing fancy. But every once in a while the setTimeout just refuses to fire.

Code essentially looks like this:

```
var c = -1;
function userInput(input)
{
    clearTimeout(c);
    c = setTimeout(function(){load(input);}, 100);
}
function load(input)
{
    console.log("load: " + input);
    // ajax stuff.
}
```

Like I said, this usually works just fine. But when it stops working the "issue" seems to be the assignment to variable `c`.

Here is a snippet from IE's debug console. If I assign the result of `setTimeout` to `c`, nothing fires. If I assign the result to something else, or dont assign it at all, it works fine.

```
>> c = setTimeout("load('test');", 100); 
303789 
>> setTimeout(function(){load('test');}, 100); 
311016 
LOG: load: test
>> clearTimeout(c) 
>> c = setTimeout(function(){load('test');}, 100); 
342177 
>> testtesttest = setTimeout(function(){load('test');}, 100); 
346296 
LOG: load: test
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else in your page has also decided to use the 'c' variable to store timer ids. That other code is clearing it before your new setTimeout gets a chance to fire. Change to use a different variable (and make its name more descriptive while you're at it).